# Placeholder not being changed when deploying maven project to tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment, build

I got maven project with pom.xml in which I replace placeholder in one of configuration files according to profile as follows:

```
<properties>
        <mq-server.host>127.0.0.1</mq-server.host>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/config</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>staging</id>
            <properties>
                <mq-server.host>local.staging.com</mq-server.host>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

When I build project using maven all doing fine on the other hand my project is Web project that is synchronizing with local tomcat via eclipse plugin and when I'm running project on tomcat using "play" button in eclipse, placeholder is not being changed. I wonder how I can fix it without adding special file just for developer.